# Generate Flash message in rails when no record is available in table

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a page in Ruby On Rails 4 in which there are two drop down are present for month and year and at the bottom there is Download button,I want the file to be downloaded only if the data is present for that month and year,else i should get an flash message that record not present.I tried in the following ways.Still its not working.

```html
def index
    @month = params[:salaryslip_component][:month]
    @year = params[:salaryslip_component][:year]
    @salary_components = SalaryComponent.all
    @salaryslips = Salaryslip.where(month: @month,year: @year)
    if @salaryslips.present? == true
      respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { send_data render_to_string(:index), :filename => 'mydoc.xml', :type=>"application/xml", :disposition => 'attachment' }
      flash[:danger] = "Salaryslip  processed"
      end
    else
    flash[:danger] = "Salaryslip not yet processed"
    end
  end
```

please help.... :)

Comment: remove "== true" from your if condition.

Comment: still no  solution...

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove `== true` after `@salaryslips.present?`, because `present?` check if there is data it will execute the code in its condition, otherwise it will not let the code run.

Second flash messages are of three types
`flash[:notice]`
`flash[:alert]`
`flash[:error]`

From the issue mentioned above, I think you should use `flash[:error]` instead of `flash[:danger]`

Comment: i tried the way you specified,still no progress...by the way thanks.... ;)

Comment: suggest me if any other way you have.